# C# ASP.Net - How to Display TextBox Based on Selected Value in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to display certain textbox based on the selected value in Dropdownlist. For some reason, it is not working - when a particular item is selected in dropdownlist, none of the inputbox is visible on the page. Hoping to get feedback. Thanks in advance.

Here is the relevant code:

aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="AreaDropDownList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AreaDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Rectangle</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Triangle</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Trapezoid</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Circle</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Sector Of Circle</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Ellipse</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

       <asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="TRUE"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="TRUE"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="TRUE"></asp:TextBox>
```

aspx.cs page:

```
protected void AreaDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedValue == "")
            {
                InputTextBox1.Visible = false;
                InputTextBox2.Visible = false;
                InputTextBox3.Visible = false;
            }

            else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedValue == "Rectangle")
            {
                InputTextBox1.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox2.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox3.Visible = false;
            }

            else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedValue == "Triangle")
            {
                InputTextBox1.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox2.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox3.Visible = false;
            }

            else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedValue == "Trapezoid")
            {
                InputTextBox1.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox2.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox3.Visible = true;
            }

            else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedValue == "Circle")
            {
                InputTextBox1.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox2.Visible = false;
                InputTextBox3.Visible = false;
            }

            else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedValue == "Sector")
            {
                InputTextBox1.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox2.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox3.Visible = false;
            }

            else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedValue == "Ellipse")
            {
                InputTextBox1.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox2.Visible = true;
                InputTextBox3.Visible = false;
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With M. Ayoub's help I was able to solve the problem by changing the code logic a bit. The following code is placed in Page_Load event function and now I can control which text box is visible:

```
if ((RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "Area Calculator") &&   (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "Trigonometric Calculator")
            && (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "Area Calculator"))
            {
                arithmetic.Visible = false;
                trig.Visible = false;
                CalcArea.Visible = false;
        }
```

Two other changes were made based on M. Ayoub's feedback: first one is using SelectedItem.Text instead of SelectedValue for dropdownlist. The second one is having a else block in AreaDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged. Code is below:

```
 protected void AreaDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text == "")
{
inputbox1.Visible = false;
                inputbox2.Visible = false;
                inputbox3.Visible = false;
                }
else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text == "Rectangle")
            {
inputbox1.Visible = true;
                inputbox2.Visible = true;
                inputbox3.Visible = false;

            }

else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text == "Triangle")
            {
               inputbox1.Visible = true;
                inputbox2.Visible = true;
                inputbox3.Visible = false;
            }

else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text == "Trapezoid")
            {
inputbox1.Visible = true;
                inputbox2.Visible = true;
                inputbox3.Visible = true;
            }

else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text == "Circle")
            {
inputbox1.Visible = true;
                inputbox2.Visible = false;
                inputbox3.Visible = false;

            }

else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text == "Sector")
            {

               inputbox1.Visible = true;
                inputbox2.Visible = true;
                inputbox3.Visible = false;
            }

else if (AreaDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text == "Ellipse")
            {
inputbox1.Visible = true;
                inputbox2.Visible = true;
                inputbox3.Visible = false;

            }

            else
            {
                inputbox1.Visible = true;
                inputbox2.Visible = true;
                inputbox3.Visible = true;
            }
```

Comment: elaborate a little more on the change needed in general in the "page Load" method please.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use `.Text` property 
instead of `.SelectedValue`
In the If statement.

```
 if (AreaDropDownList.Text == "")
            {
                InputTextBox1.Visible = false;
                InputTextBox2.Visible = false;
                InputTextBox3.Visible = false;
            }
```

Comment: Hi Ayoub, thanks for the feedback. I changed .SelectedValue to .Text, but the result is the same still.

Comment: Thanks, I have put back the else block. No change in the output is observed. What happens is when I change Dropdown list value in UI (for example from Circle to Triangle), no input box is shown. But when I click back the drop down list, I can see the inputbox for Triangle. I think it something to do with Postback, but haven't figured it out yet. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Are you writing something in your page_load event?

Comment: Yes, it has the following entry: CalcArea.Visible = false;

Comment: Commenting out this line does solve this issue, but it does not hide this particular area when the page is loaded. Is there a way to hide this area when page is loaded initially but that does not affect Dropdownlist's selection of value (hiding and displaying textboxes)?

Comment: Okay, maybe that's the problem. Put your load event code in this if statement: if (IsPostBack == false)  { //your code here ;}

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but the problem still there. I think we are very close to solving this though. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: What controller (tool) is the CalcArea?

Comment: It's just a Div tag ID. I have solved the problem now, by putting a if block in page load event for a RadioButtonList. Your pointers regarding page load event helped me rethink the logic, thanks for this. Here is the code:        if ((RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "Area Calculator") && (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "Trigonometric Calculator")
                && (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "Area Calculator"))
            {
                arithmetic.Visible = false;
                trig.Visible = false;
                CalcArea.Visible = false;
            }

Comment: Nice, Good luck !